# How should The Gentlemen's Alliance Cross be tagged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just asked a question about The Gentlemen's Alliance Cross, which I tagged as [gentlemens-alliance-cross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentlemens-alliance-cross). It could also be tagged as [the-gentlemens-alliance-cross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-gentlemens-alliance-cross) which is technically the English name, though that seemed a bit long. [shinshi-doumei-cross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shinshi-doumei-cross) is the Japanese name, but I don't know if that's the name that people would know it by, so that would probably work better as a synonym if anything.

Comment: popularity and tag having many followers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[the-gentlemens-alliance-cross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-gentlemens-alliance-cross) isn't a valid tag name because it's over 25 characters; in fact [gentlemens-alliance-cross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentlemens-alliance-cross) is already 25 characters. If you try to create it the system won't allow it. (That is, assuming nothing changed with tag naming rules). Including "the" in the tag name isn't really necessary either since search engines will just drop it. Most people here will be able to find it without the "the" at the beginning as well.

As for [shinshi-doumei-cross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shinshi-doumei-cross), since the series is licensed in English and has an official English name which fits, the English name should be preferred unless there's an extremely compelling reason not to use it. Most English speakers will either know just the English name or both names, but very few will only recognize the Japanese name. If you think there's room for confusion, you should clear it up in the tag wiki and/or propose a synonym for the Japanese name, but I don't see any special circumstances here which would merit using the Japanese name.

So IMO keep it as [gentlemens-alliance-cross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentlemens-alliance-cross).